# Property 'cookies' does not exist on type 'Request'

Tags: typescript, express, nestjs

I'm trying to read cookie in a nestjs controller.

i am following the docs at https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/cookies#use-with-express-default

Here's my code

```js
import { Controller, Get, Render, Req } from '@nestjs/common';

@Controller()
export class AppController {

  @Get()
  @Render('home')
  getHello(@Req() req: Request) {
    return { text: req.cookies['id'] };
  }
}
```

the problem is that type `Request` from express does not have `cookies`. So i get this error.

```bash
src/app.controller.ts:11:24 - error TS2339: Property 'cookies' does not exist on type 'Request'.

11     return { text: req.cookies['id'] };
                          ~~~~~~~
```

The code actually works if i remove type `Request` from `req`. But thhen i lost type-safety.

Comment: if you followed nestjs docs then I assume you installed cookie parser with its types and used it as global middleware in your app right, if so I think the problem is with the Request type I don't see where you import it in your code you should import it from express

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to import the type `Request` from `express` (so install `@types/express`). That one you're using is not from it. I'm assuming that you're the default http adapter.